# Common practices for Javascript/jQuery ajax call synchronization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, concurrency, semaphore

I am curious if this is considered good practice or what may be better. Say for instance I have to make two or more ajax calls in a row and wait for all to complete before proceeding. Also in this case I am using JSONP in order to call a service on a seperate port (same origin policy).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var semaphore = 0; 

   var proceed = function() { ... }; 

   goAjax('arg0', function(data) {

       semaphore++;
       checkStatus(semaphore, proceed);  
   }); 

   goAjax('arg1', function(data) {

       semaphore++;
       checkStatus(semaphore, proceed); 
   }); 

}

function checkStatus(sem, callback)
{
    if (sem == 2)
    {
        callback(); 
    }
}

function goAjax(args, callback) {

    $.ajax({
                ...

                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data) {
                                callback(data);                          
                },          
            }); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with what you are doing though I'd prefer to batch those two requests together. By batching, I mean consolidate it into one call and in the server that handles the request, make the two service calls that would have been otherwise called separately and then have it handled in the one callback.  Having to wait for those two calls to be completed in javascript defeats the whole purpose of making them asynchronous(ajax) calls.  Those two calls are probably called separately in certain cases but it doesn't hurt to add some mechanism in your javascript and service to handle multiple requests in one call, for cases like when it's applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I use [`after`](https://github.com/raynos/after.js) for this functionality

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var proceed = function() { ... },
       next = after(2, proceed);

   goAjax('arg0', function(data) {
       next(); 
   }); 

   goAjax('arg1', function(data) {
       next();
   }); 
}
```